# convert from string to integer of apiLink value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an apiLink for pdf open.

i want to convert **companyValue** and **empValue** into integer format.

```
`https://mobileapi.unq.co.il/api/TlushSachar/GetPrintTlushMisradHinuch?company=${companyValue}&year_month=${yearMonthValue}&employee=${empValue}`)
```

How can i convert those two value from string to integer?

Comment: why are you gonna convert  string to integer ? 
when you are sending request every params converted to string .

Comment: You can convert the string value to number using [Number Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
`https://mobileapi.unq.co.il/api/TlushSachar/GetPrintTlushMisradHinuch?company=${parseInt(companyValue)}&year_month=${yearMonthValue}&employee=${parseInt(empValue)}`)
```

You can see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt() Method
for reference [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use the following method to convert the string to a number

```
Number(companyValue)
Number(empValue)
```